# android - Testes unitários e testes de UI

Tags: android, testes, testes-de-unidade

Bom dia amigos,

ultimamente eu tenho visto alguns videos e blogs sobre o assunto, e queria saber de quem costuma trabalhar com testes se realmente vale a pena utilizar de testes no dev Android.

E se sim, quais frameworks tem melhor usabilidade para isso.

Dei uma usada rapida no `JUnit 4` e li a respeito do `uiautomatorviewer` mas nao cheguei a utilizar.

Answer (score 0):

Sempre vale a pena fazer testes. Cada Framework tem seu escopo de utilização. O Junit4 serve, por exemplo, para testes unitários que não dependem de componentes do Android para rodar (ex: teste de classes, algum método de cálculo ou manipulação de strings, etc), então eles rodam diretamente do Android Studio e não precisam de um celular ou emulador rodando. Já o Espresso é para testes de interface (clique de botões, abertura de telas, intents,  Providers, AsyncTasks, etc). O UIAtimatorViewer é para testes fora do escopo da aplicação (Ex: um outro aplicativo passando dados para o seu ou vice-versa).